# Differential equations resonance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've got the question 'Solve (c^2)y ' ' + y = 0, y(1)=1, y'(0)=0. Show that as c->0, the solution does not tend to a limit'.

From solving the equation I got the roots as +-(1/c)i, and then using set Yp=Axcos((1/c)x)+Bxsin((1/c)x)) and tried to solve, however after a lot of working i'm stuck with Asin((1/c)x)=Bcos((1/c)x) and have no idea where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your work: the general solution is $y(x) = A\cos(x/c) + B\sin(x/c)$.

As $y'(0) = 0$, it follows $B = 0$. Now solve for $A$.

Comment: Don't we need both a particular function and complementary function or am I confusing myself?

Comment: Your ODE is a homogeneous equation. There are no (non-trivial) particular solutions. The general solution is a linear combination of two linearly independent complementary solutions.

Comment: Ah ok I forgot that it didn't have a particular solution to use. From here i've got A=0 and B=1/Cos(1/c) but i'm not sure what to do next. If I substitute this in I get y=(cos(x/c))/cos(1/c). Therefore as c->0 does this make the equation resonate?

Comment: The question you ask in the OQ is "Show that as $c\rightarrow 0$, the solution does not tend to a limit". So now you want to show that the $y(x)$ you just wrote does not have a limit. That shouldn't be so bad, since the coefficient $1/\cos(1/c)$ behaves badly as $c \rightarrow 0^+$.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for your help!